# How to define variables in select statement vb.net?

Tags: sql

I have a query like this

Dim view_src_14 As String = GetParameterValue("ViewSrc14")

Dim calendar_date_14 As String = GetParameterValue("CalendarDate14")

```
select calendar_date,view_src,sum(effective) effective_total, sum(ineffective) ineffective_total 
from wrk_alert_effectiveness 
where calendar_date='" + calendar_date_14 + "' and '" + view_src_14 + "' 
group by 1,2 
order by 1 desc;
```

`calender_date_14` and `view_src_14` are variables... when I run the query it bring this error:

> invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Where do i make the changes??

Comment: Typically you would use the `DECLARE` statement, but this looks more like you are trying to insert a server-side variable into a SQL statement. When you say `calendar_date_14` and `view_src_14` are variables, are you meaning server-side variables? Like PHP or C#? And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which RDBMS you are using? Mysql, sqlite, postgresql, mssql, oracle, other?

Comment: I am using vb.net...what i need is the syntax to enclose the "calender_date_14" in the statement.

Comment: "where calendar_date = X and Y" - did you mean to use a "between" instead of "="?

Comment: What is the *exact* SQL string you are trying to execute, meaning with those parameters values filled in?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is specific enough for an answer, but it is too long for a comment.

You are trying to execute a SQL statement where you pass in values for constants in the statement.  This is allowed and a part of SQL -- using parameters.  There are two types of parameters, named parameters and positional parameters.

```
select calendar_date, view_src,
       sum(effective) as effective_total, sum(ineffective) as ineffective_total 
from wrk_alert_effectiveness 
where calendar_date = @date1 and @date2
group by 1, 2 
order by 1 desc;
```

Often, these are represented by `?` for anonymous parameters.  Sometimes named ones are introduced with colons.

The exact syntax depends on your database and the application interface you are using.  My point is that you should learn about parameters and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
"select calendar_date, view_src, sum(effective) effective_total, 
sum(ineffective) ineffective_total 
from wrk_alert_effectiveness 
where calendar_date= '" + @CalendarDate + "' AND " +  @ViewSrc + " 
group by 1,2 
order by 1 desc;"
```

Comment: Parameters are the correct idea, but not to concatenate into a SQL statement